# Mostrar botón en un elemento, lista dinamica

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

Tengo una lista dinámica de elementos que se pinta mediante un ngFor. Necesito que el botón para eliminar elementos de la lista se muestre solo al pasar el cursor por encima del elemento. Pero solo el de ese elemento. Actualmente se muestra en todos al pasar por encima el cursor.

HTML:

```
<div>
        <label>Selected Hotels:</label>
            <md-list *ngFor="let item of selectedItems">
                <md-list-item class="result-list" (mouseover)="over()" (mouseleave)="leave()">
                    <h4 md-line>{{item.name}}</h4>  <button class="button-delete" md-icon-button (click)="removeFromList($index, item)" *ngIf="showDeleteButton"><md-icon>highlight_off</md-icon></button>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
    </div>
```

Componente:

```
  over() {
    this.showDeleteButton = true;
  }
  leave() {
    this.showDeleteButton = false;
  }

  removeFromList(index, item) {
    // Otras operativas con item...
    this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi obtienes la solución. Deberías pasar a los métodos mouseover y mouseleave el item que está ejecutándose en el for y delegar el los item el que su botón sea ocultado o no.

```
<div>
    <label>Selected Hotels:</label>
    <md-list *ngFor="let item of selectedItems">
        <md-list-item class="result-list" (mouseover)="over(item)" (mouseleave)="leave(item)">
            <h4 md-line>{{item.name}}</h4>
            <button class="button-delete" md-icon-button (click)="removeFromList($index, item)" *ngIf="item.showDeleteButton"><md-icon>highlight_off</md-icon></button>
        </md-list-item>
   </md-list>
</div>


over(item) {
    item.showDeleteButton = true;
}
leave() {
    item.showDeleteButton = false;
}
```

removeFromList(index, item) {
    // Otras operativas con item...
    this.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
  }

Comment: Mil gracias, Por ahí por ahí andaba, mirando tema de indices, etc. jajaja. Muchas gracias compañero!

Comment: De nada, para estamos